# Errors during deploying rails application to server while using bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I've got a rails application, which I want to run into a docker container.

I've run bundle install .. but got this error:

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150517-474-  15nbph7.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:0:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function 'fbuffer_to_s':
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: macro "rb_str_new" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
 VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                           ^
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:20: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
 VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                ^
Makefile:237: recipe for target 'generator.o' failed
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in     /var/www/test/xyz/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/www/test/xyz/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.7.7/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

How can I install the json gem in /vendor/bundle?

gem install json -v 1.7.7 --path /vendor/bundle

dosn't work the path param isn't allowed. ...

Comment: run `rm /var/www/test/xyz/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/json-1.7.7 `, then `gem install json -v '1.7.7'`

Comment: Then I got this: You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1 directory.

Comment: you can change the directory permissions.

Comment: I've set 777 to  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ ... but the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error. This error is because of the versions of ruby softwares (gems) that we uses doesn't match at some point.

You are using ruby version 2.2.1. Your Gemfile contains the gems of older versions and it depends on json version 1.7.7.

You should install the following ruby version:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

to get rid of the error, OR updating your gems that compatible with ruby version 2.2.1 will do the trick.

Comment: This also worked for me:
sudo gem install json -v '1.8.2'